# What is the shortest notation for this regex?

Tags: regex

We've determined that this regex works for validating a certain field, but would like it to be shorter since it will be repeated numerous times:

```
\D\D\d\d\d\D\d\d\D-\d\d\d
```

**What is the shortest notation that would still validate the same as the above regex?**

Comment: "regex" is way too general. What kind of regex?

Comment: Why would you want to repeat any code at all numerous times? DRY.

Comment: Is that '-' supposed to be a literal dash?  If so it should be escaped "\-"

Comment: @eds The dash is outside a character class so there's no need to escape it.

Comment: @eds: it should only be escaped if it's within square brackets, in order to escape the meaning of a character range.

Answer (score 3):

Not really shorter, but maybe more readable.

```
\D{2}\d{3}\D\d{2}\D-\d{3}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's shorter, but this definitely is easier to read:

```
\D{2}\d{3}\D\d{2}\D-\d{3}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\D\D\d{3}\D\d\d\D-\d{3}` - only marginally shorter.

Easier to read, although longer: `\D{2}\d{3}\D\d{2}\D-\d{3}`

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
\D{2}\d{3}\D\d{2}\D-\d{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since \D{2} are 5 chars, this is shorter:

```
\D\D\d{3}\D\d\d\D-\d{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, same length but groups 3 characters that are repeated twice

```
\D{2}\d(\d{2}\D){2}-\d{3}
```